# FineUploader Delete File error when on Production Server

Tags: iis, fine-uploader

I'm using FineUploader to Upload and Delete files. My Upload process works fine on the production server. However when I tried to delete the file I get an error 500. I've checked the permission and everything looks good.

Note: Locally the Upload/Delete process work fine. The issue occurs only when I push the code to the production server. I'm using IIS 7.5 and it an HTTPS URL.

Does anyone know what could cause the error 500?

Comment: You'll have to look at your server code yourself and figure that out, most likely.  Your server is returning the 500, so, follow the request into your server and determine where it is being rejected.

Comment: I have spend a lot of time trying to resolve this issue and I can't seem to get it to work. It seems like IIS 7.5 rejects the DELETE verb. I've tried adding the Delete Verb through the Request Filtering on IIS and it still fails. Note the Upload method work fine on the server.

Answer (score 0):

A 500 usually doesn't mean that the server does not support a specific request method. That would be a 405. Most likely, some code server-side is tripping on this request. It's hard to say what the specific problem is without having access to your server.  You'll need to track the request after it hits your server and see what, specifically, is rejecting the request with a 500.

Forcing the delete file feature to use DELETE for the method has been a headache for some users.  I've created an enhancement request to allow integrators, such as yourself, to change the method used for delete file requests to POST.  See [case #831](https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/831) in the Github repo for more details.

Comment: Im referring to this information "The plan is to add a method property to the deleteFile option"

Comment: That is a feature/enhancement request, documented in the case I linked to in my answer above.

Comment: No it not release yet correct? Do you know when it will be implemented?

Comment: The release after next, or possibly this release.  You don't really need this though.  Your problem is an improperly configured web server.  If you address the issue with your server the delete requests will work fine.